# Multilingual App Toolkit doesn't generate keys in resource file

Tags: win-universal-app, multilingual, uwp, multilingual-app-toolkit

After last update of Multilingual App Toolkit (in UWP project) I have a problem with propagate keys from source to destination translations. 
My piece of project looks like: 
[image]

In the past, when I had added key to test.resw **(in en-US)** and then have used Generate Machine Translations, it added also key in test.resw (**pl-PL**).
Now, after translations I can see my translated key in .xlf file, but it is not copied to test.resw file in pl-PL. Consequently, it's still return English translation for key, because cannot find it in pl-PL.

Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Can you view code for xlf file and show typical `<trans-unit>`?

Comment: It's from my example file. In this file you can find translation, but it is not visible in test.resw file: 
  `<trans-unit id="String1" translate="yes" xml:space="preserve">
          <source>buy</source>
          <target state="needs-review-translation" state-qualifier="tm-suggestion">kup</target>
        </trans-unit>`

Comment: Have you tried to build your project - does test.resw get updated?

Comment: It's strange, but after restart VS and rebuild project everything looks great - my keys are copied to pl-PL resources. Thanks you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try to *Build* your project, Multilingual App Toolkit doesn't update *resw* files right away after you modify the main resource file.